# IApplicationBuilder does not contain UseStaticFiles()

Tags: asp.net-core

I tried different versions of StaticFiles.But it shows error because IApplicationBuilder does not contain UseStaticFiles().

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1"
```

I am using the exact code provided in the .net documentation by Microsoft. Here is what I have in Startup.cs. Note: app is an IApplicationBuilder

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    PathString.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDiriectory(), @"Files")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Files")
            });
```

To put it in context, I want to read the directories and files inside the "Files" folder.
Here is the line of code I am using to read the content of the folder but it always returns null. Note: "initialFilePath" is relative path to the folder "File".

```
var contents = _fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents(initalFilePath);
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't work.

Comment: Update to latest version and see if that helps? Start a new web project (which has static file support by default) and see your code to it (if desperate)?

Comment: I created new solution and copied all files and it works now. Thanks

Comment: I had a problem with this when I removed ApplicationInsights from an Empty project template (via Visual Studio) and then added StaticFiles. However, if I added StaticFiles first, and then removed ApplicationInsights, things worked OK -- could call app.UseStaticFiles().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find method app.UseStaticFiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568102/cant-find-method-app-usestaticfiles)

Comment: By adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles , it worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

Add nuget package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles"

Comment: Dang I shoulda scrolled down farther. I had the using statement but was missing the package, saw it on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568102/cant-find-method-app-usestaticfiles), was going to post the answer here lol

Comment: By adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles , it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Open your csproj files in notepad and make sure you have the following line.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
```

If not, add it and reload the project and rebuild.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me on an empty ASP.NET Core project in VS 2017

Answer (score 3):

You are almost certainly missing a `using` statement. The extension method `UseStaticFiles` is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` namespace. just add this to the top of your `Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the sane issue, were you ever able to resolve? I also have this package.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the issue. I tried multiple different things like, getting a fresh copy from repository, deleting the .dll and recompiling, even tried switching between different versions of nuget packages nothing worked.

Finally, I created an entirely new solution and copied my files to the new solution and now the error is gone in the new solution. It is a very tedious solution but finally it worked. Hope it will help if someone gets into the same issue.

Comment: FYI I was using VS 2015 in Windows 7