# OWIN/Katana middleware classic asp pages skipping pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin-middleware

I have a classic asp app build on top of mvc 4.5 and I am trying to intercept calls for classic asp pages and it looks like I am not able to do that. Any ideas of how. Not sure how to have the middle ware intercept those requests. Looks like this [Can't find method app.UseStaticFiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568102/cant-find-method-app-usestaticfiles) is similar but they were using a module.. I want to be able to use the middle ware.

Any thoughts ?

Adding startup.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Owin;
    using Owin;
    using System.Web;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel;
    using System.Web.Helpers;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        ConfigureAuth(app);

    }

    private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(typeof(LogMiddleware));
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {

            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            CookieDomain = MvcApplication.CookieDomian,
            CookiePath = MvcApplication.ApplicationPath,
            CookieName = "asp.net",
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        }
        });



        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);

        app.MapWhen(
            context => context.Request.Path.ToString().EndsWith(".asp"),
            appBranch =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            });
        app.Use(typeof(ResponseHeaderMiddleware));
```

Comment: Share your startup.cs please

Comment: Wow, classic asp on Owin.  I applaud your bravery.

Comment: I'm trying,not by choice,  but it doesn't intercept those calls what so ever. I suspect that it has to do with the fact that the whole point of owin is to get off of IIS. Not sure if I can mix custom http modules with owin middle ware

Comment: Marcus any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests is set to false in the web config..

Set this to true and it works... who would have guessed.